# normalcolor not working with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\color{gray}
Gray point \(X\)
\[ A = B\]

\normalcolor
Black point \(Y\)
\[ C = D\]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use the `\color` command to change the color to gray and `\normalcolor` to change back to the default color. This works for text and equations but not for nodes in tikzpicture for some reason. I expected the default color in tikzpictures to change back to black.

Is this behavior expected? How can I reset the default color of tikz?

I know that I can surround the `\color` statement with a `\begingroup -- \endgroup`, but I don't want to do that because adding groups breaks things in my particular application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*As [Ulrike Fisher](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) points out in a comment below, it is a bug in `xcolor` (its definition of `\normalcolor` is faulty, it doesn't update the `.` color.).*

Here is a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{normalcolor}{.}\def\normalcolor{\color{normalcolor}}} % workaround
\begin{document}

\color{gray}
Gray point \(X\)
\[ A = B\]

\normalcolor
Black point \(Y\)
\[ C = D\]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is not a bug in tikz but in xcolor.  Its definition of \normalcolor is faulty, it doesn't update the `.` color.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for this information.